# Как обойти ошибку bot was blocked by the user? Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Столкнулся с такой ошибкой `bot was blocked by the user aiogram`.
Нагуглил что можно использовать BotBlocked в aiogram, но что-то не срослось с ним. Наткнулся на ещё одну ошибку `inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

```
async def on_startup(dispatcher):
    cursor.execute('SELECT user_id FROM test')
    arr = cursor.fetchall()
    for user_id in arr:
       await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id[0], text="Бот запущен!")
       await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Как тут грамматно расположить try except Botblocked pass?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю примерно так

```py
from aiogram.utils.exceptions import BotBlocked

async def on_startup(dispatcher):
    cursor.execute('SELECT user_id FROM test')
    arr = cursor.fetchall()
    for user_id in arr:
       try:
           await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id[0], text="Бот запущен!")
       except BotBlocked as E:
            pass
       await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Как всегда выручаете Александр:) Не помогло, уведомление не отправил, но после ошибки sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: test.user_id , работать не перестал

Answer (score 0):

```
async def on_startup(dispatcher):
    cursor.execute('SELECT user_id FROM test')
    arr = cursor.fetchall()
    for user_id in arr:
        try:
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id[0], text="Бот запущен!")
        except BotBlocked:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Решилось так